# Does Android allow swapping processes to memory?

Tags: google-play-store

I'm  currently  doing a project  on Android  in which there are certain  questions  one of them is this one which is quite  difficult  to find. Please  help it out

Comment: What do you mean by "swapping of processes"?  I'm not sure if you're referring to multithreading (yes), the use of swap space instead of RAM (depends on the kernel), or something else.

Comment: is the swapping  of processes  allowed  or not when the memory  is full?

Answer (score 3):

There is no swap partition on Android by default. The reason they don't use a swap partition is because flash tends to be slow to write. As Matthew said, the kernel itself supports swap files (yay linux!). You could replace the kernel and you would have swap support.

However, Android does do paging. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478535/1997645) on stackoverflow as its quite useful.